# Possible to Collapse or Hide bootstrap-multiselect dropdown on mouse out?

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

Is it possible to collapse/hide the bootstrap-multiselect drop down menu if a user's mouse isn't hovering over the select menu or it's options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bootstrap dropdown you can checkout this plugin

https://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/

This should work for multiselect as well

Comment: awesome thanks.  Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but I was able to see how this library managed it and was able to roll my own solution.